# Unable to import package and module KIVY

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Any idea what I am missing here? I am trying to import functions from function.py to dashboard.py using " from  .db_functions.function import * ".

It looks like function.py cannot be found and then dashboard.kv cannot be imported to the main view.

Here is my NEW folder structure for this dashboard view, same error:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
I changed the file structure and now I am using the import as suggested in the comments:" from function import general_insert "

Comment: I don't think you need the `.` before `db_functions` in your `import` statement.

Comment: Dashboard is not importable because it crashes.  I agree with John, the very first thing, line 16 is wrong.  also it is not recommended generally to import * of a module.  do:   from my_module import one_thing, another_thing, the_last_thing  # importing

Comment: Thanks for comments guys, I changed the imports and even file structure so the file function.py is in the same folder as dashboard.py, see above edits, but unfortunately I am getting the same error, any other suggestions? I could not be more confused why this is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is as follows, (this is not a totally accurate situation but just stay with me for now) you run the package dashboard in another script from your home directory (`~/dashboard/__init__.py` for example from `~`) and that package imports another package relative to it self (`.dashboard`) so it works as it then imports from as the directory `~/dashboard/*` as it is relative to the script `__init__`, but when `dashboard.py` tries to import `functions.py`, the import path isn't relative to the `dashboard.py` but uses the default path `.`, which is set to the current directory it was started in (`~`), thas why the error occurs.

(Sorry if it's confusing, comment if you need clarification or if i said anything incorrect).

```py
home/    # '~' in this made-up situation
└─ dashboard/
   ├─ __init__.py
   ├─ dashboard.py
   └─ functions.py

# Not full step-by-step path for the import process
"""
... Script runs before hand ...

The dashboard package is run from home directory

'~/dashboard/__init__.py' is executed from '~'
'~/dashboard/__init__.py' imports '.dashboard' relatively

'~/dashboard' package is directly searched for 'dashboard.py': FOUND

'~/dashboard/dashboard.py' is executed from '~'
'~/dashboard/dashboard.py' imports 'functions' universally

'~' is searched for 'functions.py': NOT FOUND
'sys.path' is searched for 'functions.py': NOT FOUND

'~/dashboard/dashboard.py' complains module is not found
Error is raised
"""
```

A useful source where it explains a bit more on python's imports:

[https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#how-imports-work:~:text=The%20first%20thing,is%20searched%20first.](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#how-imports-work:%7E:text=The%20first%20thing,is%20searched%20first.)

> The first thing Python will do is look up the name *abc* in **sys.modules**. This is a cache of all modules that have been previously imported.
>
> If the name isn’t found in the module cache, Python will proceed to search through a list of **built-in modules**. These are modules that come pre-installed with Python and can be found in the Python Standard Library. If the name still isn’t found in the built-in modules, Python then searches for it in a list of directories defined by **sys.path**. This list usually includes the current directory, which is searched first.

EDIT: Crude work-around

Python searches in a specific way to import modules and to ensure it finds the module in your case, you can directly put the directory containing the script into the search path to make sure it is found and imported when needed.

```py
# Add this to the beginning of dashboard.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\RFQMS\\views\\dashboard\\")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried importing this function.py in a lot of ways possible and the one you suggested " from .function import general_insert " also does not work and giving me same error as above "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function'". I already spent 2 days researching it to solve it, but there is very little about Kivy + Python with the similar structure to what i wan to use. All solutions point to what you described and the link you attached I have read many times. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, the least I know from your log is that kivy fails to load the .kv file as dashboard.py fails to find the functions.py script. You could harcode a direct path into sys.path to see if it can import it then. You could make it inside dashboard.py itself to make sure the path containing functions is searched

Comment: Add `sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\RFQMS\\views\\dashboard\\")` to the beginning of dashboard.py just after importing `sys`. This should force python to search the correct folder for `functions.py`

Comment: sys.path.insert solutions worked! thanks very much for this MOStudios! I need to read more about this to understand what is happening. Again thanks very much, grab that 50 bounty :D :D Merry Christmas :D

Comment: I'll update my answer to explain the issue :) Happy to help.